# Why do I get many Removable Disk icons that don't really exist?

Tags: windows-7

Since I can remember, my Windows 7 always shows 6 icons for fictitious Removable Disks. They aren't a problem, really - when I insert a real USB stick, it shows as yet another icon (but working).

But they are a mystery, and I've always wondered where they come from, why are there 6 Removable Disk icons for disks that don't really exist. 
If I try to open any of them, I only get this dialog saying:

> Please insert a disk into Removable Disk K:

[image]

So where do these icons come from? I most definitely don't have 6 USBs attached to my computer, or anything like that.

Comment: Please list all your devices installed in your device.  `Speccy` is great for something like that even allows you to link to all the information after you have copied the relevant details into the question.

Comment: I don't know where it came from,but we can hide these Empty Drives.

Comment: have you tried to test it with a new copy of windows on another drive? or using linux ie ubuntu and boot it in live mode. If the problem is from your computer using ubuntu live helps. I think its a virus or so ......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get something very similar on a PC with a multiformat memory card reader. It can read SD-Card, Sony Memory-stick, Compact-Flash etc. It shows up as several removable media devices even though mostly there are 0 or at most 1 of them with any content.

I don't get this effect on other computers.

So it can be a feature (tm) of the way the device hardware interacts with the Windows driver.

Comment: My computer is an HP and it does have a memory card reader.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, your put me on the right direction, I posted it in an answer here.

Comment: OK, I also found the devices in the Hardware tab, it really is the card reader - anyone interested can see my answer http://superuser.com/a/868516/66282. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RedGrittyBrick, his suggestion put me on the right direction.

I needed to check "Hide empty drives in the Computer folder" and then also set to "Don't show hidden file, folders, or drives".

I also noticed that if "Hide empty drives..." and "Show hidden files..." are checked, the drives are shown, but slightly transparent, just like how hidden files are slightly transparent.

[image]

Also upon further investigation I found this:

[image]

So it really does seem be because of the SD Card reader, as @RedGrittyBrick suggested.

So mystery solved :)

Comment: This should be an edit to your question.